# SQL - raise error if a select statement returns the "wrong" number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm working with Oracle but I would be interested in whether this is possible in any sql flavor. Essentially I have a long select statement; I need to confirm that the select returns a certain number of records (the output of a separate select count(*)) and I haven't been able to figure out how to do this programmatically (or solve the problem that prevents me from knowing that my query is 100% correct from the get-go).

Ideally, I want to add a few lines so that, either the correct set is returned, or an error is thrown

Comment: With enough time and effort I could probably do it in sql server.  As with all difficult tasks I would do one thing at a time.  The first thing I would do in this case is to throw an error.  The second would be to throw and error based on very simple conditional logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is done on MS-SQL but I'm sure you could easily make it work for Oracle if you felt inclined:

```
DECLARE @err_message nvarchar(255)
set @err_message = 'Doesnt match count expected'

IF
(select count(*) [Counter] from(
    select ordernum from erp.orderhed where ordernum > 390000) as Ordercount) <> 3412
raiserror(@err_message,11,1)

ELSE

select ordernum from erp.orderhed where ordernum > 390000
```

In this example I know (because I checked) that there is exactly 3412 rows that will be returned from that query, so it'll go into the ELSE and return my query (which could be stored as a view for readability). If that count changes then it will raise the exception with the message I wrote.

I'm not sure how you mean to use it but I'd imagine this would fit into a stored procedure fairly well.

Comment: would your approach require executing the same query twice?

Comment: In this example yes, which may or may not matter for what you're trying to accomplish. 

If its a heavy query and performance matters (which it likely does) then you could load the contents into a temp table, then evaluate whether to return it or throw an error. Then you're only incurring the cost of the query once. You will incur the cost of querying the temp table though.

I'm not sure of a way to run the query, hold the contents in limbo while we evaluate our condition, then return them with only the cost of the single select.

Comment: yea doubling the cost is what I want to avoid. I had the thought to add ',count(*) as tot' to the select clause, which wouldn't raise an error per se but also wouldn't require two passes?

Comment: Right but if you return all the rows with a count column, each cell is only going to have a value of 1 because Count is basically Sum(# of rows) with a group by. I had the idea of a Row Count, so each row is numbered 1, 2, 3, etc... Then you could look at the Max(RowCountColumn) and see if it matches? That could do it. Again, its T-SQL but heres a link to the documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/186133/how-to-dynamically-number-rows-in-a-select-transact-sql-statement